# Getting a function to multiply or sum based on the first element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I am having some trouble writing a function that will sum all the elements of a list or multiply all the elements of a list together based on whether the first element of the list is odd or even.
I would like to get something like this.

```
def simpleSum(mylist):
    #Write your code
    number = 1
    for n in mylist:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            return sum(mylist)
        else:
            number *= n
            return number

print(simpleSum([1, 2, 4, 5]))
print(simpleSum([2, 4, 5, 6]))
```

I added the `number = 1` and `number *= n` based on what I've seen on the internet, but I don't really understand why I have to use `number = 1` and also what `number *= n` is doing.

I would like my output to be

```
12
240
```

but so far I keep getting

```
12
2
```

Very new to python, and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I originally tried using

```
for n in mylist:
        if n[0] % 2 != 0:
```

but I kept getting an error telling me that `n[0]` is not scriptable.

Any brief explanation would help me tremendously. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should _first_ check the parity of the first list member (learn how to access the first list member) and _then_ either return the sum or calculate and return the product in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there

The answer to your question is extremely simple. All you need to correct is your logic or your syntax.

Let us break your program down and try to understand where the error is.

```
def simpleSum(mylist):
    #Write your code
    number = 1
    for n in mylist:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            return sum(mylist)
        else:
            number *= n
            return number

print(simpleSum([1, 2, 4, 5]))
print(simpleSum([2, 4, 5, 6]))
```

The code `for n in mylist` returns one element of the list at a time, and not the position, so when you say `n[0]`, it returns an error as it is not a list and doesn't have any indexes.

Next up, looking at your logical or syntax error:

If you notice carefully, `n` becomes the next index of the list everytime. This means that everytime it checks whether the number is odd or even. If it is odd, it returns with the sum, but if it is even, it returns with number multiplied by n. Since it returns at first entry itself, i.e, at the first index itself, this means that if the number is even, the result will be that number(because 1*n=n) and if it is odd, it will return the sum of the whole list.

To change this, the following logic is used.
Create function:
If the first index of the list i.e., `mylist[0]` is odd:
return the sum
Otherwise/else:
return the product

The code to reproduce this would be:

```
def simpleSum(mylist):
    #Write your code
    if mylist[0] % 2 != 0:
        return sum(mylist)
    else:
        number = 1
        for n in mylist:
            number *= n
        return number

        

print(simpleSum([1, 2, 4, 5]))
print(simpleSum([2, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your desired output and inputs, you want the list of numbers multiplied if the first element is even and the sum of the list of numbers if the first element is odd.

- `number = 1` acts as a base value for multiplication.
- `number *= n` equals to `number = number * n`

Consider the following code. First, it checks whether the first value of the list is odd or even. Then it calculates and returns values accordingly.

```py
def simpleSum(mylist):
    if (mylist[0] % 2) == 0:
        number = 1
        for n in mylist:
            number *= n
        return number
    else:
        return sum(mylist)

print(simpleSum([1, 2, 4, 5]))
print(simpleSum([2, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is doing what you want. If I'm reading your description correctly, it sounds like you want to know whether the first element of your list is even or odd *before* you add or multiply all the elements together.

In that case, you want something like this:

```
if my_list[0] % 2 == 0:
    print(sum(my_list)
else:
    num = 1
    for n in my_list:
        num *= n
    print(num)
```

The reason you need to set `num = 1` is because `num *= n` multiplies `num` by `n`, and if `num` doesn't have an initial value, you can't multiply it by `n`!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for the multiplication part

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def my_func(some_list):
    return sum(some_list) if some_list[0] % 2 else reduce(mul, some_list)

print(my_func([1, 2, 4, 5]))
print(my_func([2, 4, 5, 6]))
```

output

```
12
240
```